# Are complexity classes sets?

Tags: set-theory, definition, computer-science, computational-complexity

The definition of a complexity class reads in various different sources roughly as "a collection/set/... of decision problems".
My question is: Is every complexity class a set (in the sense of axiomatic set theory)? Or are there complexity classes which are proper classes (as the name might suggest)?

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: They are sets (though classes can be sets as well - a class does not have to be proper). A decision problem is just some subset of $\Sigma^*$ - that is, an element of $P(\Sigma^*)$ - so a complexity class is a subset of $P(\Sigma^*)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. For complexity classes containing decision problems, the answer is that they are just sets. Note that a decision problem is precisely a language; that is, a set $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^{*}$. The functional analogues of these classes (e.g., $\textsf{FP}$, the complexity class containing functions which are polynomial-time computable) are also sets.

It may be possible that when one delves deeply into logic, there are complexity classes which are proper classes. I am not a logician, so I do not know. Nor have I ever heard of this happening from complexity theorists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll mark it as accepted, however it would still be nice if someone has an example for the latter case to mention it.